# How can I set default indentation for bullet list in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Default for bullet lists is 0.25in.  I want 0.00in.
Default for hanging indent is 0.25in.  I want 0.20in.
How can I set default for all future Word documents, forever?
It will NOT work to make a new template with these indents in the Paragraph style.  That will apply them to ALL paragraphs, but I want to apply them ONLY to BULLET lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly increase / decrease. I am not sure about 0.0 but you might. The key tool is the Indent Style List in Word and make / save a new list style. You might need more than one style for more than one use. I have a screen shot below with the key points taken from Word 2007 (long out of support).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this has no effect on new documents.  In other words, it does not override the default indents.  It only changes the indents on the current document while that document is open.  If you close the document, reopen it, and create a new bullet list, the new list has the old default settings.  I just tried it.

Comment: Click the option above for "New Documents based on this Template"  Then in Save section, you need to Save the Template. You should make just one or two changes so you can change back if need be.  I highlighted the option above.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried it.
The "template" I generated looks like a Word doc.  I have to open that specific doc to try to generate a bullet list formatted the way I want. When I open the "template", it still contains the dummy bullet list I made up.  If I delete that dummy list, create a new list, and bullet that list, my settings are ignored.  After closing, it becomes an ordinary Word document, with default settings.  The original "template" is still there, with the dummy bullet list formatted the way I want.
The "template" is no good for creating new content or new documents' settings.

Comment: Word 2007 was a very old attempt to create templates. If this does not work, you may need to upgrade to a newer version of Office.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Microsoft strikes again! :-(
Thanks for taking the time try to come up with a solution. BTW, afterwards when I was working with a non-bulleted document, MS insisted on putting hanging indents on every paragraph, just as it would for a bullet list.  So I had to go in and fix that.  That seems to have been the only lasting effect of attempting to override the default bullet list format.